# Network bonding active-backup mode with two switches

Tags: networking, bonding, redundancy

This below is a sample of my network. I have two interfaces on one machine eth0: 192.168.150.2 and eth1: 192.168.150.3 and I want make my network redundant  using mode=1 which is active-backup, so if one switch fails I want to still have traffic to both interfaces. The switch A is connected to ASA firewall which in this case is the gateway with IP: 192.168.175.3 . I'm not sure when configuring the bond0 interface what IP address should i set if the gateway has IP 192.168.175.3 .

```
            |                                     |
            |                                     |
      +-----+----+                          +-----+----+
      |          |             ISL          |          |
      | switch A +--------------------------+ switch B |
      |          |                          |          |
      +-----+----+                          +-----++---+
            |                                     |  
            |             +-------+               |
            +-------------+ host1 +---------------+
                     eth0 +-------+ eth1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When bonding, you will not assign IP address to individual eth0 or eth1 interfaces (slave interfaces), only to the bond0 (Master Interface). So assign 192.168.150.2 to the bond0 interface, and remove IP Address information from eth0 and eth1.

Comment: for example the configuration for the bond0 interface would be: ... IPADDR=192.168.150.2 NETMASK=255.255.255.0 GATEWAY=192.168.170.3 etc..

Comment: Correct. This site has useful information regarding bundling/bonding links, and what else is needed.

https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bonding